Merged vertices don't save on export
In the model I'm trying to edit, there are seams on certain parts that break the texture, making a very visible lines. These spots are actually two sets of vertices in the identical place, and merging them seems to solve the issue. However, after I export the model, everything reverts, as seen in Substance Painter, where the seams appear again on the old spots. This happens regardless of whether I apply the animroot modifier manually or not. When the exported model is imported back to Blender, all the vertices are still merged. They are not anywhere beyond Blender. What am I doing wrong?

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Are you sure you are importing the correct model into substance painter?

@TheLabCat Yes, I am importing the correct model.

In that case, I’m pretty sure this is a Substance Painter problem, not a Blender problem.
